# iOS dark mode preferredColorScheme works "almost" fine ... .contextMenu still not being changed

Tags: swiftui, darkmode

Trying to implement dark mode in SwiftUI and .preferredColorScheme apparently is the way to do it.

But the .contextMenu { ... } still not being changed with the system UI theme.

Is that because .contextMenu uses a UIKit or and older framework ?

Anyone went thought that already ?
Thanks in advance for your feedback!

... as you can see in the 4th image, the context menu still white, and should be black...

[image: as you can see in the 4th image, the context menu still white, and should be black]

here's the code to illustrate the issue :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("interfaceTheme") var interfaceTheme: InterfaceTheme = .dark
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Theme")
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                Spacer()
                Picker("Theme", selection: $interfaceTheme, content: {
                    ForEach(InterfaceTheme.allCases, id:\.self) { scheme in
                        Text(scheme.name).tag(scheme)
                    }
                })
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                    .padding(.leading)
            }.padding()
            Spacer().frame(height: 50)
            Text("hold for context menu")
                .padding().foregroundColor(Color(.systemBackground)).background(.blue).cornerRadius(15)
                .contextMenu {
                    Button {
                        //
                    } label: {
                        Text("not the right color")
                    }
                }
        }
        .padding()
        .preferredColorScheme(interfaceTheme == .light ? .light : interfaceTheme == .dark ? .dark : nil)
    }
}

enum InterfaceTheme: Int, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case auto = 0
    case light = 1
    case dark = 2
    var id: Int { self.rawValue }
    
    var name: String {
        switch self {
            case .auto: return String("auto")
            case .light: return String("light")
            case .dark: return String("dark")
        }
    }
}
```

the interface should look like this :

[image: right color]

Comment: Why the complicated ternary? Why not `.preferredColorScheme(vm.interfaceTheme)`? Otherwise, post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: because iOS ColorScheme only have .light or .dark as enums, so I need a way to set a nil ...

Comment: Why is vm.interfaceTheme not an optional? Define it as `var interfaceTheme: ColorScheme?` and you can set it to `.light`, `.dark` or `nil`.

Comment: That could be a possibility. Thank you for your concern Yrb.

But the point of my question is actually that .preferredColorScheme do not change the color of some UI items, as the .contextMenu ...

Comment: You need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How are you using all this?

Comment: here's the example code @Yrb.

Comment: We can't build and run that code. You need to strip it of unnecessary lines and add the code that we need to run it like your view model. You should be able to run the code you post in a new project.

Comment: @Yrb, my fault… I removed the vm to simplify.

Comment: After running it, that looks like the correct color for the context menu. I don't think you can change it from Apple's defaults. Were you expecting it to be something like white text on a black background?

Comment: I'm sorry @Yrb, but context menu on native dark mode have a black background.

Try running with the auto selected on the picker, with the simulator on dark mode and hold for the context menu. 

(cmd shiftt A to toggle dark mode on simulator ...)

Comment: Gotcha. That looks like a bug. I would file a radar and post the number here.

Comment: You mean to Apple directly ?

Thank you for your time by the way ...

Comment: here we go : FB9883497

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in iOS 17.2
I checked the behavior in the simulator and it looks like `.contextMenu` respects `UIUserInterfaceStyle`. Therefore, in this case this code will help:

```
guard let window = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene)?.windows.first else { return }
guard interfaceTheme == .dark else { return }
window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```